# How to utilize Lightweight Charts library in flutter using webview

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, flutter-layout, lightweight-charts

I am interested in using the Lightweight Charts in flutter potentially using webview. Here's an example of code that I want to be integrated. https://jsfiddle.net/TradingView/qrb9a850/

Javascript code:

```js
function createSimpleSwitcher(items, activeItem, activeItemChangedCallback) {
    var switcherElement = document.createElement('div');
    switcherElement.classList.add('switcher');

    var intervalElements = items.map(function(item) {
        var itemEl = document.createElement('button');
        itemEl.innerText = item;
        itemEl.classList.add('switcher-item');
        itemEl.classList.toggle('switcher-active-item', item === activeItem);
        itemEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
            onItemClicked(item);
        });
        switcherElement.appendChild(itemEl);
        return itemEl;
    });

    function onItemClicked(item) {
        if (item === activeItem) {
            return;
        }

        intervalElements.forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.classList.toggle('switcher-active-item', items[index] === item);
        });

        activeItem = item;

        activeItemChangedCallback(item);
    }

    return switcherElement;
}

var intervals = ['1D', '1W', '1M', '1Y'];

var dayData = [
    { time: '2018-10-19', value: 26.19 },
    { time: '2018-10-22', value: 25.87 },
    { time: '2018-10-23', value: 25.83 },
    { time: '2018-10-24', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2018-10-25', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-10-26', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2018-10-29', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-10-30', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2018-10-31', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-11-01', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-11-02', value: 25.74 },
    { time: '2018-11-05', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2018-11-06', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-07', value: 25.73 },
    { time: '2018-11-08', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-09', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-12', value: 25.76 },
    { time: '2018-11-13', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2018-11-14', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2018-11-15', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-16', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-19', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-20', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-11-21', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2018-11-23', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-11-26', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2018-11-27', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2018-11-28', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2018-11-29', value: 25.55 },
    { time: '2018-11-30', value: 25.41 },
    { time: '2018-12-03', value: 25.41 },
    { time: '2018-12-04', value: 25.42 },
    { time: '2018-12-06', value: 25.33 },
    { time: '2018-12-07', value: 25.39 },
    { time: '2018-12-10', value: 25.32 },
    { time: '2018-12-11', value: 25.48 },
    { time: '2018-12-12', value: 25.39 },
    { time: '2018-12-13', value: 25.45 },
    { time: '2018-12-14', value: 25.52 },
    { time: '2018-12-17', value: 25.38 },
    { time: '2018-12-18', value: 25.36 },
    { time: '2018-12-19', value: 25.65 },
    { time: '2018-12-20', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2018-12-21', value: 25.66 },
    { time: '2018-12-24', value: 25.66 },
    { time: '2018-12-26', value: 25.65 },
    { time: '2018-12-27', value: 25.66 },
    { time: '2018-12-28', value: 25.68 },
    { time: '2018-12-31', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2019-01-02', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-01-03', value: 25.69 },
    { time: '2019-01-04', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2019-01-07', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-01-08', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-01-09', value: 25.66 },
    { time: '2019-01-10', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2019-01-11', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2019-01-14', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2019-01-15', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2019-01-16', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-01-17', value: 25.99 },
    { time: '2019-01-18', value: 25.60 },
    { time: '2019-01-22', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2019-01-23', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2019-01-24', value: 25.74 },
    { time: '2019-01-25', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2019-01-28', value: 25.83 },
    { time: '2019-01-29', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2019-01-30', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2019-01-31', value: 25.35 },
    { time: '2019-02-01', value: 25.60 },
    { time: '2019-02-04', value: 25.65 },
    { time: '2019-02-05', value: 25.73 },
    { time: '2019-02-06', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2019-02-07', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2019-02-08', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-02-11', value: 25.76 },
    { time: '2019-02-12', value: 25.84 },
    { time: '2019-02-13', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2019-02-14', value: 25.87 },
    { time: '2019-02-15', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2019-02-19', value: 25.90 },
    { time: '2019-02-20', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2019-02-21', value: 25.96 },
    { time: '2019-02-22', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-02-25', value: 25.93 },
    { time: '2019-02-26', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2019-02-27', value: 25.67 },
    { time: '2019-02-28', value: 25.79 },
    { time: '2019-03-01', value: 25.86 },
    { time: '2019-03-04', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2019-03-05', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2019-03-06', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2019-03-07', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2019-03-08', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2019-03-11', value: 25.91 },
    { time: '2019-03-12', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2019-03-13', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-03-14', value: 26.05 },
    { time: '2019-03-15', value: 26.11 },
    { time: '2019-03-18', value: 26.10 },
    { time: '2019-03-19', value: 25.98 },
    { time: '2019-03-20', value: 26.11 },
    { time: '2019-03-21', value: 26.12 },
    { time: '2019-03-22', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2019-03-25', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2019-03-26', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-03-27', value: 25.73 },
    { time: '2019-03-28', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2019-03-29', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2019-04-01', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2019-04-02', value: 25.93 },
    { time: '2019-04-03', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2019-04-04', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2019-04-05', value: 26.16 },
    { time: '2019-04-08', value: 26.12 },
    { time: '2019-04-09', value: 26.07 },
    { time: '2019-04-10', value: 26.13 },
    { time: '2019-04-11', value: 26.04 },
    { time: '2019-04-12', value: 26.04 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 26.05 },
    { time: '2019-04-16', value: 26.01 },
    { time: '2019-04-17', value: 26.09 },
    { time: '2019-04-18', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-04-22', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-04-23', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2019-04-24', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-04-25', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2019-04-26', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2019-04-29', value: 25.91 },
    { time: '2019-04-30', value: 25.90 },
    { time: '2019-05-01', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2019-05-02', value: 25.97 },
    { time: '2019-05-03', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2019-05-06', value: 26.03 },
    { time: '2019-05-07', value: 26.04 },
    { time: '2019-05-08', value: 26.05 },
    { time: '2019-05-09', value: 26.05 },
    { time: '2019-05-10', value: 26.08 },
    { time: '2019-05-13', value: 26.05 },
    { time: '2019-05-14', value: 26.01 },
    { time: '2019-05-15', value: 26.03 },
    { time: '2019-05-16', value: 26.14 },
    { time: '2019-05-17', value: 26.09 },
    { time: '2019-05-20', value: 26.01 },
    { time: '2019-05-21', value: 26.12 },
    { time: '2019-05-22', value: 26.15 },
    { time: '2019-05-23', value: 26.18 },
    { time: '2019-05-24', value: 26.16 },
    { time: '2019-05-28', value: 26.23 },
];

var weekData = [
    { time: '2016-07-18', value: 26.10 },
    { time: '2016-07-25', value: 26.19 },
    { time: '2016-08-01', value: 26.24 },
    { time: '2016-08-08', value: 26.22 },
    { time: '2016-08-15', value: 25.98 },
    { time: '2016-08-22', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2016-08-29', value: 25.98 },
    { time: '2016-09-05', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2016-09-12', value: 25.84 },
    { time: '2016-09-19', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2016-09-26', value: 25.65 },
    { time: '2016-10-03', value: 25.69 },
    { time: '2016-10-10', value: 25.67 },
    { time: '2016-10-17', value: 26.11 },
    { time: '2016-10-24', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2016-10-31', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2016-11-07', value: 25.40 },
    { time: '2016-11-14', value: 25.32 },
    { time: '2016-11-21', value: 25.48 },
    { time: '2016-11-28', value: 25.08 },
    { time: '2016-12-05', value: 25.06 },
    { time: '2016-12-12', value: 25.11 },
    { time: '2016-12-19', value: 25.34 },
    { time: '2016-12-26', value: 25.20 },
    { time: '2017-01-02', value: 25.33 },
    { time: '2017-01-09', value: 25.56 },
    { time: '2017-01-16', value: 25.32 },
    { time: '2017-01-23', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2017-01-30', value: 25.85 },
    { time: '2017-02-06', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2017-02-13', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2017-02-20', value: 25.67 },
    { time: '2017-02-27', value: 25.60 },
    { time: '2017-03-06', value: 25.54 },
    { time: '2017-03-13', value: 25.84 },
    { time: '2017-03-20', value: 25.96 },
    { time: '2017-03-27', value: 25.90 },
    { time: '2017-04-03', value: 25.97 },
    { time: '2017-04-10', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2017-04-17', value: 26.13 },
    { time: '2017-04-24', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2017-05-01', value: 26.30 },
    { time: '2017-05-08', value: 26.27 },
    { time: '2017-05-15', value: 26.24 },
    { time: '2017-05-22', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2017-05-29', value: 26.20 },
    { time: '2017-06-05', value: 26.12 },
    { time: '2017-06-12', value: 26.20 },
    { time: '2017-06-19', value: 26.46 },
    { time: '2017-06-26', value: 26.39 },
    { time: '2017-07-03', value: 26.52 },
    { time: '2017-07-10', value: 26.57 },
    { time: '2017-07-17', value: 26.65 },
    { time: '2017-07-24', value: 26.45 },
    { time: '2017-07-31', value: 26.37 },
    { time: '2017-08-07', value: 26.13 },
    { time: '2017-08-14', value: 26.21 },
    { time: '2017-08-21', value: 26.31 },
    { time: '2017-08-28', value: 26.33 },
    { time: '2017-09-04', value: 26.38 },
    { time: '2017-09-11', value: 26.38 },
    { time: '2017-09-18', value: 26.50 },
    { time: '2017-09-25', value: 26.39 },
    { time: '2017-10-02', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2017-10-09', value: 26.15 },
    { time: '2017-10-16', value: 26.43 },
    { time: '2017-10-23', value: 26.22 },
    { time: '2017-10-30', value: 26.14 },
    { time: '2017-11-06', value: 26.08 },
    { time: '2017-11-13', value: 26.27 },
    { time: '2017-11-20', value: 26.30 },
    { time: '2017-11-27', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2017-12-04', value: 26.10 },
    { time: '2017-12-11', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2017-12-18', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2017-12-25', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-01-01', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2018-01-08', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2018-01-15', value: 26.03 },
    { time: '2018-01-22', value: 26.04 },
    { time: '2018-01-29', value: 25.96 },
    { time: '2018-02-05', value: 25.99 },
    { time: '2018-02-12', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2018-02-19', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2018-02-26', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2018-03-05', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2018-03-12', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2018-03-19', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-03-26', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-04-02', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2018-04-09', value: 25.73 },
    { time: '2018-04-16', value: 25.74 },
    { time: '2018-04-23', value: 25.69 },
    { time: '2018-04-30', value: 25.76 },
    { time: '2018-05-07', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2018-05-14', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2018-05-21', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2018-05-28', value: 25.79 },
    { time: '2018-06-04', value: 26.11 },
    { time: '2018-06-11', value: 26.43 },
    { time: '2018-06-18', value: 26.30 },
    { time: '2018-06-25', value: 26.58 },
    { time: '2018-07-02', value: 26.33 },
    { time: '2018-07-09', value: 26.33 },
    { time: '2018-07-16', value: 26.32 },
    { time: '2018-07-23', value: 26.20 },
    { time: '2018-07-30', value: 26.03 },
    { time: '2018-08-06', value: 26.15 },
    { time: '2018-08-13', value: 26.17 },
    { time: '2018-08-20', value: 26.28 },
    { time: '2018-08-27', value: 25.86 },
    { time: '2018-09-03', value: 25.69 },
    { time: '2018-09-10', value: 25.69 },
    { time: '2018-09-17', value: 25.64 },
    { time: '2018-09-24', value: 25.67 },
    { time: '2018-10-01', value: 25.55 },
    { time: '2018-10-08', value: 25.59 },
    { time: '2018-10-15', value: 26.19 },
    { time: '2018-10-22', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2018-10-29', value: 25.74 },
    { time: '2018-11-05', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-12', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-11-19', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-11-26', value: 25.41 },
    { time: '2018-12-03', value: 25.39 },
    { time: '2018-12-10', value: 25.52 },
    { time: '2018-12-17', value: 25.66 },
    { time: '2018-12-24', value: 25.68 },
    { time: '2018-12-31', value: 25.71 },
    { time: '2019-01-07', value: 25.92 },
    { time: '2019-01-14', value: 25.60 },
    { time: '2019-01-21', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2019-01-28', value: 25.60 },
    { time: '2019-02-04', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2019-02-11', value: 25.89 },
    { time: '2019-02-18', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-02-25', value: 25.86 },
    { time: '2019-03-04', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2019-03-11', value: 26.11 },
    { time: '2019-03-18', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2019-03-25', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2019-04-01', value: 26.16 },
    { time: '2019-04-08', value: 26.04 },
    { time: '2019-04-15', value: 26.00 },
    { time: '2019-04-22', value: 25.88 },
    { time: '2019-04-29', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2019-05-06', value: 26.08 },
    { time: '2019-05-13', value: 26.09 },
    { time: '2019-05-20', value: 26.16 },
    { time: '2019-05-27', value: 26.23 },
];

var monthData = [
    { time: '2006-12-01', value: 25.40 },
    { time: '2007-01-01', value: 25.50 },
    { time: '2007-02-01', value: 25.11 },
    { time: '2007-03-01', value: 25.24 },
    { time: '2007-04-02', value: 25.34 },
    { time: '2007-05-01', value: 24.82 },
    { time: '2007-06-01', value: 23.85 },
    { time: '2007-07-02', value: 23.24 },
    { time: '2007-08-01', value: 23.05 },
    { time: '2007-09-03', value: 22.26 },
    { time: '2007-10-01', value: 22.52 },
    { time: '2007-11-01', value: 20.84 },
    { time: '2007-12-03', value: 20.37 },
    { time: '2008-01-01', value: 23.90 },
    { time: '2008-02-01', value: 22.58 },
    { time: '2008-03-03', value: 21.74 },
    { time: '2008-04-01', value: 22.50 },
    { time: '2008-05-01', value: 22.38 },
    { time: '2008-06-02', value: 20.58 },
    { time: '2008-07-01', value: 20.60 },
    { time: '2008-08-01', value: 20.82 },
    { time: '2008-09-01', value: 17.50 },
    { time: '2008-10-01', value: 17.70 },
    { time: '2008-11-03', value: 15.52 },
    { time: '2008-12-01', value: 18.58 },
    { time: '2009-01-01', value: 15.40 },
    { time: '2009-02-02', value: 11.68 },
    { time: '2009-03-02', value: 14.89 },
    { time: '2009-04-01', value: 16.24 },
    { time: '2009-05-01', value: 18.33 },
    { time: '2009-06-01', value: 18.08 },
    { time: '2009-07-01', value: 20.07 },
    { time: '2009-08-03', value: 20.35 },
    { time: '2009-09-01', value: 21.53 },
    { time: '2009-10-01', value: 21.48 },
    { time: '2009-11-02', value: 20.28 },
    { time: '2009-12-01', value: 21.39 },
    { time: '2010-01-01', value: 22.00 },
    { time: '2010-02-01', value: 22.31 },
    { time: '2010-03-01', value: 22.82 },
    { time: '2010-04-01', value: 22.58 },
    { time: '2010-05-03', value: 21.02 },
    { time: '2010-06-01', value: 21.45 },
    { time: '2010-07-01', value: 22.42 },
    { time: '2010-08-02', value: 23.61 },
    { time: '2010-09-01', value: 24.40 },
    { time: '2010-10-01', value: 24.46 },
    { time: '2010-11-01', value: 23.64 },
    { time: '2010-12-01', value: 22.90 },
    { time: '2011-01-03', value: 23.73 },
    { time: '2011-02-01', value: 23.52 },
    { time: '2011-03-01', value: 24.15 },
    { time: '2011-04-01', value: 24.37 },
    { time: '2011-05-02', value: 24.40 },
    { time: '2011-06-01', value: 24.45 },
    { time: '2011-07-01', value: 24.24 },
    { time: '2011-08-01', value: 24.00 },
    { time: '2011-09-01', value: 22.77 },
    { time: '2011-10-03', value: 24.21 },
    { time: '2011-11-01', value: 23.40 },
    { time: '2011-12-01', value: 23.90 },
    { time: '2012-01-02', value: 24.84 },
    { time: '2012-02-01', value: 25.04 },
    { time: '2012-03-01', value: 24.90 },
    { time: '2012-04-02', value: 25.06 },
    { time: '2012-05-01', value: 24.63 },
    { time: '2012-06-01', value: 25.07 },
    { time: '2012-07-02', value: 25.30 },
    { time: '2012-08-01', value: 25.08 },
    { time: '2012-09-03', value: 25.27 },
    { time: '2012-10-01', value: 25.39 },
    { time: '2012-11-01', value: 25.06 },
    { time: '2012-12-03', value: 25.03 },
    { time: '2013-01-01', value: 25.26 },
    { time: '2013-02-01', value: 25.20 },
    { time: '2013-03-01', value: 25.30 },
    { time: '2013-04-01', value: 25.38 },
    { time: '2013-05-01', value: 25.22 },
    { time: '2013-06-03', value: 24.88 },
    { time: '2013-07-01', value: 24.98 },
    { time: '2013-08-01', value: 24.60 },
    { time: '2013-09-02', value: 24.65 },
    { time: '2013-10-01', value: 24.62 },
    { time: '2013-11-01', value: 24.65 },
    { time: '2013-12-02', value: 24.70 },
    { time: '2014-01-01', value: 24.98 },
    { time: '2014-02-03', value: 24.95 },
    { time: '2014-03-03', value: 25.45 },
    { time: '2014-04-01', value: 25.40 },
    { time: '2014-05-01', value: 25.51 },
    { time: '2014-06-02', value: 25.34 },
    { time: '2014-07-01', value: 25.30 },
    { time: '2014-08-01', value: 25.36 },
    { time: '2014-09-01', value: 25.16 },
    { time: '2014-10-01', value: 25.53 },
    { time: '2014-11-03', value: 25.40 },
    { time: '2014-12-01', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2015-01-01', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2015-02-02', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2015-03-02', value: 25.63 },
    { time: '2015-04-01', value: 25.39 },
    { time: '2015-05-01', value: 25.62 },
    { time: '2015-06-01', value: 25.23 },
    { time: '2015-07-01', value: 25.47 },
    { time: '2015-08-03', value: 25.18 },
    { time: '2015-09-01', value: 25.30 },
    { time: '2015-10-01', value: 25.68 },
    { time: '2015-11-02', value: 25.63 },
    { time: '2015-12-01', value: 25.57 },
    { time: '2016-01-01', value: 25.55 },
    { time: '2016-02-01', value: 25.05 },
    { time: '2016-03-01', value: 25.61 },
    { time: '2016-04-01', value: 25.91 },
    { time: '2016-05-02', value: 25.84 },
    { time: '2016-06-01', value: 25.94 },
    { time: '2016-07-01', value: 26.19 },
    { time: '2016-08-01', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2016-09-01', value: 25.65 },
    { time: '2016-10-03', value: 25.80 },
    { time: '2016-11-01', value: 25.06 },
    { time: '2016-12-01', value: 25.20 },
    { time: '2017-01-02', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2017-02-01', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2017-03-01', value: 25.90 },
    { time: '2017-04-03', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2017-05-01', value: 26.02 },
    { time: '2017-06-01', value: 26.39 },
    { time: '2017-07-03', value: 26.30 },
    { time: '2017-08-01', value: 26.14 },
    { time: '2017-09-01', value: 26.39 },
    { time: '2017-10-02', value: 26.12 },
    { time: '2017-11-01', value: 25.81 },
    { time: '2017-12-01', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-01-01', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2018-02-01', value: 25.78 },
    { time: '2018-03-01', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-04-02', value: 25.72 },
    { time: '2018-05-01', value: 25.75 },
    { time: '2018-06-01', value: 26.58 },
    { time: '2018-07-02', value: 26.14 },
    { time: '2018-08-01', value: 25.86 },
    { time: '2018-09-03', value: 25.67 },
    { time: '2018-10-01', value: 25.82 },
    { time: '2018-11-01', value: 25.41 },
    { time: '2018-12-03', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2019-01-01', value: 25.35 },
    { time: '2019-02-01', value: 25.79 },
    { time: '2019-03-01', value: 25.77 },
    { time: '2019-04-01', value: 25.90 },
    { time: '2019-05-01', value: 26.23 },
];

var yearData = [
    { time: '2006-01-02', value: 24.89 },
    { time: '2007-01-01', value: 25.50 },
    { time: '2008-01-01', value: 23.90 },
    { time: '2009-01-01', value: 15.40 },
    { time: '2010-01-01', value: 22.00 },
    { time: '2011-01-03', value: 23.73 },
    { time: '2012-01-02', value: 24.84 },
    { time: '2013-01-01', value: 25.26 },
    { time: '2014-01-01', value: 24.98 },
    { time: '2015-01-01', value: 25.95 },
    { time: '2016-01-01', value: 25.55 },
    { time: '2017-01-02', value: 25.70 },
    { time: '2018-01-01', value: 26.06 },
    { time: '2019-01-01', value: 26.23 },
];

var seriesesData = new Map([
  ['1D', dayData ],
  ['1W', weekData ],
  ['1M', monthData ],
  ['1Y', yearData ],
]);

var switcherElement = createSimpleSwitcher(intervals, intervals[0], syncToInterval);

var chartElement = document.createElement('div');

var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(chartElement, {
    width: 600,
  height: 300,
    layout: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        textColor: '#d1d4dc',
    },
    grid: {
        vertLines: {
            visible: false,
        },
        horzLines: {
            color: 'rgba(42, 46, 57, 0.5)',
        },
    },
    rightPriceScale: {
        borderVisible: false,
    },
    timeScale: {
        borderVisible: false,
    },
    crosshair: {
        horzLine: {
            visible: false,
        },
    },
});

document.body.appendChild(chartElement);
document.body.appendChild(switcherElement);

var areaSeries = null;

function syncToInterval(interval) {
    if (areaSeries) {
        chart.removeSeries(areaSeries);
        areaSeries = null;
    }
    areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries({
    topColor: 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.56)',
    bottomColor: 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.04)',
    lineColor: 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 1)',
    lineWidth: 2,
    });
    areaSeries.setData(seriesesData.get(interval));
}

syncToInterval(intervals[0]);
```

```css
.switcher {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #2196F3;
}

.switcher-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #262b3e;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
}

.switcher-item:hover {
    background-color: #f2f3f5;
}

.switcher-active-item {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
    color: #262b3e;
}

.switcher-active-item,
.switcher-active-item:hover {
    background-color: #e1eff9;
}
```

And unpkg link: https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts@3.8.0/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js

So how I can potentially combine all of it to display in the app.

Comment: Here is a helpful guide on how to use a WebView in Flutter: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-native-communication-bridge-in-flutter-with-webview-and-javascript/

Also, please note that the JSFiddle example is using v3.4.0 and there may be a few small changes required to get it working on v3.8.0